# Using Local Storage with Forms on Multiple Pages

Tags: javascript, html, forms, local-storage

Each time the user enters info in the textboxes, I want save everything they entered to create an array of persons objects and save them using local storage. For example if the user enters Name: James, Occupation: doctor & Name: Sam, Occupation: nurse then the array would be

```
var person = [
{name:"James",
 occupation: "doctor"
},
{name:"Sam"
 occupation: "nurse"
];
```

On the second page I will make a separate div for each person, display an image for each person inside, and all the data from the form page(similar to a year book). I know the 5 methods are setItem(),getItem(), removeItem(), clear(), & key(). But, I'm having trouble with getting started on the local storage part and making an new object in the array each time the user completes the form. I'm not sure how to keep saving all data every single time the form is filled out, save the data in local storage, and then retrieve that local storage data on the second page to use in the div. Here is my code so far:

HTML(FORM PAGE)

```
<form onsubmit="return myFunction();">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <p>Name: </p>
      <td><input id="name" type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
      <p>Occupation: </p>
      <td><input id="occupation" type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>
          <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </table>
</form>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function myFunction() {
var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
var occupation = document.getElementById("occupation").value;

  if (name == "") {
    alert("You forgot to enter your name!");
  }
if (occupation == "") {
    alert("You forgot to enter your occupation!");
  }
}
```

**Note:** I'm not sure if this can be done using jQuery or other languages but I'm using only Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate the form using myFunction and if the form is validated then can add the form contents to localstorage JSON array.

```
        function myFunction() {
            var fname = document.getElementById("name").value;
            var foccupation = document.getElementById("occupation").value;

            if (fname == "") {
               alert("You forgot to enter your name!");
               document.getElementById("name").focus();
               return false;
            }
            else if (foccupation == "") {
               alert("You forgot to enter your occupation!");
               document.getElementById("occupation").focus();
               return false;
            }
            else {
                // get array called "pepple" from local storage and then add to it
                var allPeople = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("people"));
                console.log(allPeople);

                if(allPeople===null) {
                     // first time - the array is not in the localstorage yet
                     allPeople = {items:[{name:fname, occupation:foccupation}]};                        
                }
                else {
                    allPeople.items.push({name:fname, occupation:foccupation});
                }

                //console.log(allPeople);
                localStorage.setItem("people", JSON.stringify(allPeople) );

                // go to next page
                document.location = "page2.html";
                return false;
            }
            return false;

        }
```

On the next page there can be a div like this -

```
<div id="allpeopledisplay"></div>
```

and the javascript to populate the same like this.

```
        <script>
            var allPeople = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("people"));

            var allPeopleDiv = document.getElementById('allpeopledisplay');

            console.log(allPeople);
            console.log(allPeople.items.length);
            for(var i = 0; i < allPeople.items.length; i++) {
                var person = allPeople.items[i];
                console.log(person);                        
                allPeopleDiv.innerHTML += "<div>Name: "+person['name']+"<br/>Occupation: "+person['occupation']+"<hr></div>";

            }  
        </script>
```

Comment: The only way the array is created is if the user enters inputs. So for this line: var allPeople = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("people")); how are you getting the array if its not even created? Because when you first start, if the user hasn't entered anything then there is no array until they enter something. So I'm confused on how your getting it if we don't even know it's been made. @T.Shah

Comment: Also for the java on the second script, is that using template literals? I think I kind of have an idea about what they are but I have not learned them in depth yet, is there another way to write the script code without using them? @T.Shah

Comment: var allPeople = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("people"));  If the array is not in local storage, it will return null.  There is a check for that in the script.  I have commented it, too. If there is no array, it will be created, otherwise the next item will be pushed -added to the array.  In the second page script if you must have atleast a div tag with id 'allpeopledisplay'.  You can change the name of the id if you wish.  Hope this helps.